# Web scraping problem when scraping different projects

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

I have been scraping this website https://registry.verra.org/
I scrape the information through this link: [https://registry.verra.org/uiapi/resource/resourceSummary/{id}](https://registry.verra.org/uiapi/resource/resourceSummary/%7Bid%7D)
id is the id of the project I scrape there is over 4000 of projects, and there is different information from project to project. For example here:
https://registry.verra.org/uiapi/resource/resourceSummary/3628
https://registry.verra.org/uiapi/resource/resourceSummary/3658
and here:
https://registry.verra.org/uiapi/resource/resourceSummary/1
So some field pop ups and because I scrape it this way:

```
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from urllib import request

api_url = "https://registry.verra.org/uiapi/resource/resourceSummary/3628"
info_gathered = {'Heading': [], 'ID': [],'State' : [], 'Category': [], 'Proponent': [],
                 'Project Status': [], 'EAER': [], 'Project Type': [],
                 'Methodology': [], 'Project Validator': [], 'Project_registration': [],
                 'CPT': [], 'File_link': []}
data = requests.get(api_url).json()

html = request.urlopen(api_url).read()
heading = data['resourceName']
ID = data['resourceIdentifier']
i = data['participationSummaries'][0]
print(i['attributes'])
Category = i['programCode']
if len(data['attributes']) == 2:
    State = data['attributes'][1]['values'][0]['value']
elif len(data['attributes']) == 1:
    State = "None"
Proponent = ''
for nume in range(0, len(i['attributes'][0]['values'])):
    if nume != (len(i['attributes'][0]['values'])-1):
        Proponent = Proponent + i['attributes'][0]['values'][nume]['value'] + ', '
    if nume == (len(i['attributes'][0]['values'])-1):
        Proponent = Proponent + i['attributes'][0]['values'][nume]['value'] + '.'
Project_Status = i['attributes'][1]['values'][0]['value']
EAER = i['attributes'][2]['values'][0]['value']
Project_type = i['attributes'][3]['values'][0]['value']
Methodology = i['attributes'][4]['values'][0]['value']
Project_Validator = i['attributes'][5]['values'][0]['value']
```

I constantly need to change something from project ot project ot get all the info available on the pages of different projects.
How can i handle this?

Comment: you can use `if/else` to run different code on different pages. Or you can use `try/except` to catch error when it can't find element and skip this value or set some default value (i.e. `None`)

Comment: Yeah but in this case it will not work still cause on one page one object is attribute[2] then on another the same object is attribute[3] because one is missing and I cannot find a way how to access them in different way

Comment: maybe first try to get `attribute[3]` and if it raise error then try `attribute[2]` - and use `try/except` to catch error. OR maybe use `len(attribute)` to check how many attributes you have - or `attribute[-1]` to get always last attribute.

Comment: BTW: every attribute has also `["code"]` and maybe you should use this value to search correct attribute. It would need to use some `for`-loop to check code for all attributes. And if you find correct `code` then you can get value. And before for-loop you may assign default value for this object - and if it will not find this code then you will have default value.

Comment: Yeah that's also a great option. Let's say I get code attributes and after that how to access value list?

Comment: standard rule: if you have `list` then use `for`-loop to work with every item on list. i.e. `for item in i['attributes']: print(item["code"], item["values"])`